# Compare controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

sorry about not making myself clear enough and not putting enough effort (wont happen again :)). i'm building a form App where users have to fill out the form. i have a TabControl with 3 TabItem one of the TabItem has TextBoxes the second has TextBoxes and RadioButton and third has only CheckBoxes. i have written a code to dictect error by on clicking submit using ValidationRule/ValidationResult and and using GroupBinding (got it from msdn samples). now the problem am having is code to search through the tabs, compare the controls (e.g. controlA,controlB) to know wich one comes before the other and return the tabindex. one of the use i want with this is letting the user jump to the uncompleted TextBox,RadioButton or CheckBoxes in order like starting from the first Tabitem in the TabControl

with this code i could work the tree to locate the controls(code from  [Philipp Sumi blog](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent) but i modified it a little)

```
        private void Button_Click(
            object sender, 
            RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerator enumerator = FindLogicalChildren(_parentStackPanel).GetEnumerator();

         while (enumerator.MoveNext())
           MessageBox.Show(enumerator.Current.ToString());
    }


    private IEnumerable FindLogicalChildren(
        DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            foreach (object childObj in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(depObj))
            {
                DependencyObject child = childObj as DependencyObject;
                if (child != null && child is Control)
                {
                    yield return (Control)child;
                }
                foreach (Control childOfChild in FindLogicalChildren(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but i dodnt know how continue to get the tabindex of each control in order form as i work down the tree. can any one please help me on this? Thanks

im using this method:

```
        private int Compare(
        Control controlA,
        Control controlB)
    {
        DependencyObject commonAncestor = controlA.FindCommonVisualAncestor(controlB);

        for (int index = 0; index < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(commonAncestor); index++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(commonAncestor, index);
            Control control = (Control)childVisual;
            control.TabIndex = index;
        }

        return controlA.TabIndex.CompareTo(controlB.TabIndex);
    }
```

that returns 1,-1 or 0 to compare two controls to find out which one comes before the other. the question is, can anyone tell me a better way of doing this.

Comment: Compare? as comparing the control content or the control reference to see if you are referring to the same control?

Comment: And which control do you want to compare? TextBox? Date control?

Comment: don, you should put a little more effort in a question. This could have 100 answers, none stand out.

Comment: How do I read your mind in Stackoverflow?

Comment: don, there is an __Edit__ link under your question, please use that instead of creating (non-)answers.

Comment: don/austinslik, please __Delete__ your own answers below.

Comment: What I understand from your questions is:
You have tab control that contain various controls and a submit button below that. The user need to fill data in the the fields of the tab control and click submit button. If the user leaves any field as empty, you need to point out it and goes to the tab which contains the control to be filled. Is it Ok?

Comment: yes, and when hit the tab the focus will jump to the next error control that the user suppose to complete.